# Generics typescript, why does this code throw an error Type '{}' cannot be assigned to a type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, generics

I can't figure out why this code is throwing an error. - Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Keys<T>'.

```
type Keys<T extends string|symbol>={
    [key in T]: string;
};
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a:Keys<T> = {}
    return a
}
```

Moreover, if you manually substitute the string or symbol type, no errors will be received. Just a warning that T is declared for a function but not used.

Example of working codes:

```
type Keys<T extends string|symbol>={
    [key in T]: string;
};
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a:Keys<string> = {}
    return a
}
```

```
type Keys<T extends string|symbol>={
    [key in T]: string;
};
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a:Keys<symbol> = {}
    return a
}
```

You can check the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVKEAewIDsAmCUCwATgJY4DmAPgiALYBGA9gDYB8AvAN4BQUAqAG0A1vCgUoKALoAuIqQqUA3LwC+qgMbMcxKADNmzKJyip0WXAQXkqtBiw4AKAJSd2fQVG27gUAIaycIio7CZQ3Gr8giQQwACuJDgB6rxpAPTpUsasEP5JUPTMsQEs8X7AABbQrP5U8f6UEAA03qxkmiKlzABu0JIARACiGP70YLkIA1DFUAMA6pX+wADkhAByEADuAwB0vJlQAPJVECRbZAgtUE1+xPnYeFCMIFCxRT1KUKdX3sz09FwwEIdSepygW2KrCelygIGYiSgE38IEoJAR+H2AiAA)

I expected generic code to work fine

Comment: `{}` is an empty object. Why do you think it *should* be assignable?

Comment: @Pointy 
Okay, if you try to remove the symbol type and try to set a non-empty object, you will also get an error

Comment: Regardless of wether slotting `string` in there works, how would you expect `foo<{ a: string }>().a` to work if you populate that property? This is what Typescript is trying to warn you about.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Typescript treats wide property types like `string` much more leniently than property types like `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`.

---

First of all, your `Keys` type is just the built in `Record` type which is defined as:

```
type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }
```

So I'm going to use that instead for simplicity.

---

So why is this the case?

```
function foo<T extends string | symbol>() {
  const foo: Record<string, string> = {} // fine
  const bar: Record<T, string> = {} // error
}
```

The answer is because Typescript behaves differently when a key type is infinite, versus when the key type is finite.

- `string` could be *any* string, which string is not tracked.
- `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` is a finite list of strings.

Typescript doesn't bother enforcing the existence of infinite keys because it can't. The type says that any string returns a value, Typescript lets you use it like that.

And this does cause some problems:

```
const obj: Record<string, string> = { a: 'test' }
obj.b.toUpperCase() // no type error, crash at runtime
```

A better type for that would be:

```
const obj: Record<string, string | undefined> = { a: 'test' }
obj.b.toUpperCase() // type error
obj.b?.toUpperCase() // fine
```

Here the value type might be `undefined` which means we would have to make sure each property has a value before we treat it as a `string`. This gives us type safety back.

But when the compiler *can know the keys*, then it can enforce those keys, and the type checking gets much stricter:

```
const obj: Record<'a', string> = { a: 'test' }
obj.b.toUpperCase() // type error
```

Since this now has enough information to apply stronger types, it does.

---

So what's going here:

```
const foo = <T extends string|symbol>()=>{
    const a: Record<T, string> = {} // type error
    return a
}
```

Is that Typescript thinks that `T` is probably going to be inferred as a finite subset of `string | symbol`, and not the infinite wider type of `string | symbol`. So it applies the stricter type checking.

And Typescript is right. Your code does not assign any properties at all, but the types says that this should work:

```
foo<{ a: number }>().a // number
```

But your code doesn't ever assign that property so you will get `undefined` at runtime and that will probably crash something else.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
const foo = <T = "a" | "b">()=>{
    const a: {a: string, b: string} = {} // <- incompatible
    return a
}
```

Comment: Why a: {a: string, b: string}? And NOT a:{[key in string]:string}={}

Comment: I understand you mean a:Keys<'a'|'b'>, but how i can fix it i want to  get in generic only type string or symbol?

Comment: Code only answers are not recommended. Please describe why "incompatible"